# Most efficient way to split spark DataFrame depending on rules

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to split a DataFrame (~200M rows) in the most efficient way.
Here is a test sample to explain:

```
df.show()

+----+------+--------+
| id | size | weight |         
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 10   |  200   |
| 2  | 50   |  100   |
| 3  | 75   |  300   |
+----+------+--------+
```

I'm trying to split this dataframe into 2 sets like a valid and error file (or at least save directly to my hdfs as parquet files) depending on filters, for example, size > 50 & weight > 300, so I can split my dataframe on that filter.

My first intuition was to create a boolean column (0,1), depending on different filters, then sum up these new columns to finally apply a filter >0 and ==0 to create my 2 sets.

Is this an efficient way or do you think there are better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea that you propose sounds good. Following it, and once you have defined `df`, I would suggest a piece of code like the following:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn("Check_Column", F.when((F.col("size") > 50) && (F.col("weight") > 300),F.lag(1)).otherwise(0))
df2.show()
```

The above will add a new column with boolean entries corresponding to whether your conditions are met. Then, I would filter out these results in order to create the two datasets that you are after:

```
df_True = df2.filter(df2.Check_Column == 1)
df_True.show()

df_False = df2.filter(df2.Check_Column == 0)
df_False.show()
```